# Difference between proper time and coordinate time

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, time

Lately, I have been studying General Relativity, and I am very confused about the difference between proper time ($\tau$) and coordinate time ($t$).

Also, whenever we write any line element given a particular metric—let's say the Minkowski Metric for example—we always write it as:

$$ds^{2} = -dt^{2} + dx^{2} + dy^{2} + dz^{2}.$$

What does $dt$ represent over here, coordinate time or some time which is measured by some other observer?

Comment: $dt$ is coordinate time. That means the time as it is measured by some inertial frame. Is that the doubt?

Comment: The usual notation is that an inertial frame is denoted by $\{\partial/\partial t, \partial/\partial x,\partial/\partial y,\partial/\partial z\}$, with $\partial/\partial t$ being timelike.

Comment: Are you learning General Relativity without learning Special Relativity first? Students normally first encounter proper time vs. coordinate time in SR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refer you to Einstein's Paper " Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter  Körper 1905 ". He introduces a thought experiment with two inertial systems K and k. K assumed stationary and k moving. B is a fixed point in k,    B : (x',y,z) by  τ=t=0 a light ray is emitted from overlapped origins of K and k. "  x=vt+x'=ct and τ=(τ_0 +τ_2)/2, τ_0=t=x'/(c-v), τ_2=x'/(c+v) is the time the reflected light at B arrives the origin of moving k. So, τ is half of the time, light travels to B and is reflected back to the origin of the moving frame. t is the same for stationary frame K. if the observer is assumed to be in K and K is stationary, then τ = a[t-vx'/(c^2-v^2)]<t   otherwise if an observer is in k, k would be supposed stationary and K moving and t would replace τ.

Answer (score 3):

Proper time is the time measured by a clock. Because it is the reading of a clock it has a direct and clear physical interpretation. It is given by the spacetime interval calculated along the worldline of the clock: $$c^2 d\tau^2 =-ds^2$$ Because the spacetime interval is invariant, all frames will agree on the reading of any clock at any given event.

Coordinate time is simply the time coordinate in a coordinate chart that has a time coordinate. Not all coordinate charts have a time coordinate, although most useful charts do. Being a coordinate the coordinate time has only the physical meaning given it by whomever chose the coordinate system.

Comment: So the coordinate time would depend on how one would define our charts for their coordinate system? But in some textbooks, coordinate time is defined to be the time measured by the person sitting at infinity. So is this coordinate time and coordinate time defined as a real coordinate in 4D spacetime related? If I want to define the time measured by a clock at the satellite wrt to the clock on the earth, can I define the clock on the earth as a coordinate time?

Comment: *"But in some textbooks, coordinate time is defined to be the time measured by the person sitting at infinity."* - would you provide a citation? Maybe you're thinking about the particular Schwarzschild coordinate system in the Schwarzschild geometry? But there are (infinitely many) other coordinate systems for which this isn't the case, correct?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal said “But in some textbooks, coordinate time is defined to be the time measured by the person sitting at infinity”. That is true for specific coordinate charts, like the Schwarzschild chart. But it is not always true. That is why I said “coordinate time has only the physical meaning given it by whomever chose the coordinate system”

Comment: Ok thanks, so in general, coordinate time could be anything which is defined according to a particular coordinate chart with time as one of the parameters?

Comment: Yes, that is right